# Kafkajs. Lot of error logs being generated and how to handle it

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I have been noticing or a while, a lot of error logs being generated from kafkajs.

Sometimes it just doesn't stop stop. Some of the example of the logs are the following.

Log1

> ,\"logger\":\"kafkajs\",\"message\":\"[Connection]
> Connection error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS
> connection was
> established\",\"broker\":\"example.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092\",\

Log2

> \"logger\":\"kafkajs\",\"message\":\"[Connection]
> Connection
> timeout\",\"broker\":\"example.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092\",\"clientId\":\"kafkajs\"}\

Log 3

> "logger\":\"kafkajs\",\"message\":\"[Connection] Response
> LeaveGroup(key: 13, version:
> 3)\",\"broker\":\"b15-pkc-ymrq7.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092\",\"clientId\":\"kafkajs\",\"error\":\"This
> is not the correct coordinator for this
> group\",\"correlationId\":137,\"size\":14}"}},{"id":"37469739927058600437790300805508989141911926331258437637","timest

Sometimes Kafka keeps functioning properly but still spams this error logs. Can I know what is the reason and what is the best way to handle it?

Comment: What version of kafkajs are you using? There was recently a version released that fixed some disconnection issue like this. But also, you cannot control if/when Confluent upgrades the brokers, which may cause intermediate client disconnects

Comment: I knew about that. I updated. I am using 2.2.4. But still there a lot of similar logs from some to time.